# Additional python library not working on macos

Tags: python, macos, pip, ccxt

I'm using MacOS 10.14.6, and python 3.7.4

My personal python code is working well.
I've installed additional library using pip:

`pip install ccxt`

Then below code works well on windows.

```
import ccxt
bitmex = ccxt.bitmex()
print(bitmex.fetch_ticker('BTC/USD'))
```

But on MacOS, error occurred.
Who can help me?

Comment: Can you provide the error, please?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without the error. Please [edit] to add it, including traceback.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/5834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem for 3 days.
At mac , must install python3 for ccxt.

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
brew install python3
pip3 install ccxt

After above command run, error fixed.